# Application not working after submitting it to the play store

Tags: android

When i build my application on my phone trough android studio it works correctly but after the upload on google play store something happened and it won't start.
Once i open the application i face the error unfortunately app has stopped working! i'm really confused! any suggestion?

**Error Logs:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallRefe‌​rrerReceiver: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallRef‌​errerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rando.tunisie.navigationbarforallactivitites-‌​1/base.apk"],nativeL‌​ibraryDirectories=[/‌​vendor/lib, /system/lib]
```

Comment: What's the crash log you're getting from you Google Play developers console?

Comment: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rando.tunisie.navigationbarforallactivitites-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]'

Comment: Please include more information. Especially those of Manifest, Gradle Files, whether or not you use License Lib, MainActivity if possible?

Comment: You need to add the crash log to you actual question not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to proguard usage.

> Try changing Proguard.cfg file to exclude obfuscating android.gms.*

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

This should work.

Comment: how is that my friend!

Comment: Updated for you. If it works, please do leave a note. So that others might know.